# How to display div only once for session

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to show this loader on my wordpress site only once for a user session, for the moment it is shown every time the page is loaded:

```
if(location.href === "http://www.example.com/") {
    jQuery(window).load(function() {
        jQuery(".famous-loader-overlay").delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
    });
}
else {    
    jQuery(".famous-loader-overlay").delay(0).hide();
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: The only way I can think you'd be able to do this is to create a cookie and then use that gauge if the user has been on the page before. Read here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: It depends on what you are calling a "session".  As far as the browser is concerned, you could store a variable in 'sessionStorage', which would be removed when their window closed.  However if they opened another window while the first window was open, they'd see it again.

Comment: I solved the problem but when I close and open the site the browser cache don't show the loader. How I can fix? I used the variale sessionStorage.get and .set. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you only have to add another session variable and call it properly seting on it to true o false state.

you can acomplish this with local set to true storage as value on variable :

`localStorage.setItem('loaderShowed', true);`

Comment: thanks it works but the loader when showed disappear instantly. Can I  add more time to watch it?

Comment: great, i think that you have to increase the time in milliseconds for your `fadeOut(1000)` function